# Trigger on insert from table 1 to insert row into table 2 if the data is unique, update if it's not

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to make a trigger that, upon an insert into table1, checks if the same values from 3 columns in table2 match, if not it inserts that row into table2. If there is a match it then updates the row that matches. Here's what I've gathered so far, but it doesn't do the IF EXISTS check I need it to. I'm not certain how exactly to structure it in this case due to never having worked with triggers.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_Name on Table_Name
FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO
TABLE 2
(

Col1,
Col2,
Col3,
Col4

)

SELECT

(

Col1,
Col2,
Col3,
Col4

)

FROM 
INSERTED

GO
```

The IF EXISTS criteria need to see if table1.col1=table2.col1, table1.col2=table2.col2, table1.col3,table2.col3

Using SQL server 2008. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table2
SET    col1 = inserted.col1
     , col2 = inserted.col2
     , col3 = inserted.col3
     , col4 = inserted.col4
FROM   table2
 INNER
  JOIN inserted
    ON inserted.col1 = table2.col1
   AND inserted.col2 = table2.col2
   AND inserted.col3 = table2.col3
;

INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
SELECT col1
     , col2
     , col3
     , col4
FROM   inserted
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   table1
         WHERE  col1 = inserted.col1
         AND    col2 = inserted.col2
         AND    col3 = inserted.col3
       )
;
```